# Implementing Game Outcomes with While Loop: Turn-based Dueling Game

Tags: c++, loops, oop

**Background**
I'm making a turn-based dueling game against a computer. Right now, I'm trying to get the barebones of the game to work without player input. After each turn (one action by the player or computer) one of four possibilities can happen:

1. Player lives and computer lives
2. Player lives and computer dies
3. Player dies and computer lives
4. Player dies and computer dies (ex: player's attack damages the player too. Haven't done anything with that yet)

**Problem**
I can't figure out how to make the program stop when possibilities 2,3, or 4 happen. Right now, the entire thing runs and the player and computer die, even when the player should live with my current code.

**Code**
Here's a minimum working example of my current efforts. I know I'm doing something dumb, but I just can't pinpoint it. Any suggestions/pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>

class Player
{
private:
    int m_hp {};
    int m_action {};

public:

    Player(int hp = 5): m_hp{hp} 
    {

    }

    int attack(const int& attackDamage)
    {
        return attackDamage;
    }

    int getHP() const // const because getHP shouldn't alter hp
    {
        return m_hp;
    }

    void takeHP(int damage)
    {
        m_hp = m_hp - damage;
    }

    void giveHP(int healing)
    {
        m_hp = m_hp + healing;
    }


};



class Computer
{
private:
    int m_hp {};
public:

    Computer(int hp = 5): m_hp{hp}
    {

    }

    int attack(const int& attackDamage)
    {
        return attackDamage;
    }

    int getHP() const // const because getHP shouldn't alter hp
    {
        return m_hp;
    }

    void takeHP(int damage)
    {
        m_hp = m_hp - damage;
    }

    void giveHP(int healing)
    {
        m_hp = m_hp + healing;
    }
 

};





int healthCheck(Player& player, Computer& computer)
{

    if (player.getHP() > 0 && computer.getHP() > 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (player.getHP() > 0 && computer.getHP() <= 0)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (player.getHP() <= 0 && computer.getHP() > 0)
    {
        return 3;
    }
    else if (player.getHP() <= 0 && computer.getHP() <= 0)
    {
        return 4;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

}

int gameStatus(int healthCheck, Player& player, Computer& computer)
{
    switch(healthCheck)
    {
        case 1:
            std::cout << "The battle continues." << "\n";
            std::cout << "Player HP: " << player.getHP() << "\n";
            std::cout << "Computer HP: " << computer.getHP() << "\n";
            return 1;
        break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "The monster has been slain";
            // add looting function here in future 
            // Will add money to player object here with addmoney()
            return 2;
        break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << "The player has been slain";
            return 3;
        break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << "Both duelers have been slain";
            return 4;
        break;

        default:
            std::cout << "error: received an int not 1,2,3,4";
            return 5;
        break;
    }

}

void playerTurn(Player& player, Computer& computer)
{
    computer.takeHP(1);

}

void computerTurn(Player& player, Computer& computer)
{
    player.takeHP(1);
}

int main()
{
    // initialize player and computer
    Player player {};
    Computer computer {};

    int gameCondition{1};

    // game should continue while the player is still alive
    while(gameStatus(gameCondition, player, computer) == 1)
    {
        playerTurn(player, computer);
        // attempt at checking the game status after each turn
        gameCondition = healthCheck(player,computer); 
        gameStatus(gameCondition, player, computer);

        computerTurn(player, computer);
        gameCondition = healthCheck(player,computer);
        gameStatus(gameCondition, player, computer);
    }

    std::cout << "The battle is over" << "\n";


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why you say the player should not die. Player and computer take same number of hits each time round the loop and they start with same HP

Comment: I would think you'd want to check the return value of `gameStatus` when you call it inside the loop and if it returns a "game over" status use `break;` to exit the loop. The loop condition should be based on something else, like asking the player if they want to continue or quit or just an endless loop. Since both have the same number of hit points the computer dies before the player but that status isn't checked so the dead computer takes another turn and kills the player too.

Comment: @pm100 Yeah; so I guess that's my issue. In the final round, the player hits the computer first, and so in that instance, the player would have 1 HP and the computer would have 0 HP. I want the game to end at that moment, but what I have right now doesn't do that.

Comment: @RetiredNinja gotcha; that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only test the status at the top of the loop,

do this if you want to exit immediately

```
   // game should continue while the player is still alive
    while(gameStatus(gameCondition, player, computer) == 1)
    {
        playerTurn(player, computer);
        // attempt at checking the game status after each turn
        gameCondition = healthCheck(player,computer); 
        if(gameStatus(gameCondition, player, computer) != 1)  <<<<=====
           break;

        computerTurn(player, computer);
        gameCondition = healthCheck(player,computer);
        // test not needed here since its tested at the start of the loop
        gameStatus(gameCondition, player, computer);
    }
```